# Memcached using way too much memory

Tags: php, mysql, memcached, ram, phpfastcache

`free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         24028      23636        392          0        345       8104
-/+ buffers/cache:      15186       8842
Swap:         2015        852       1163`

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  19232  1140 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:16 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   1:30 [migration/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:31 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [stopper/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   1:29 [migration/1]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [stopper/1]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:28 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   1:27 [migration/2]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [stopper/2]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:30 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [watchdog/2]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   1:21 [migration/3]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [stopper/3]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:30 [ksoftirqd/3]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [watchdog/3]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   1:15 [migration/4]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [stopper/4]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:30 [ksoftirqd/4]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [watchdog/4]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   1:26 [migration/5]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [stopper/5]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:28 [ksoftirqd/5]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [watchdog/5]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   1:08 [migration/6]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [stopper/6]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:29 [ksoftirqd/6]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [watchdog/6]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   1:34 [migration/7]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [stopper/7]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:29 [ksoftirqd/7]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [watchdog/7]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:18 [events/0]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:13 [events/1]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:13 [events/2]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:13 [events/3]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:13 [events/4]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:13 [events/5]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:14 [events/6]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:17 [events/7]
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events/0]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events/1]
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events/2]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events/3]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events/4]
root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events/5]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events/6]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events/7]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_long/0]
root        52  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_long/1]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_long/2]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_long/3]
root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_long/4]
root        56  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_long/5]
root        57  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_long/6]
root        58  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_long/7]
root        59  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_power_]
root        60  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_power_]
root        61  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_power_]
root        62  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_power_]
root        63  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_power_]
root        64  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_power_]
root        65  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_power_]
root        66  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [events_power_]
root        67  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [cgroup]
root        68  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [khelper]
root        69  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [netns]
root        70  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [async/mgr]
root        71  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [pm]
root        72  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:01 [sync_supers]
root        73  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:01 [bdi-default]
root        74  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kintegrityd/0]
root        75  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kintegrityd/1]
root        76  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kintegrityd/2]
root        77  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kintegrityd/3]
root        78  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kintegrityd/4]
root        79  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kintegrityd/5]
root        80  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kintegrityd/6]
root        81  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kintegrityd/7]
root        82  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:02 [kblockd/0]
root        83  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:01 [kblockd/1]
root        84  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kblockd/2]
root        85  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kblockd/3]
root        86  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kblockd/4]
root        87  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10  12:22 [kblockd/5]
root        88  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kblockd/6]
root        89  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kblockd/7]
root        90  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kacpid]
root        91  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kacpi_notify]
root        92  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kacpi_hotplug]
root        93  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [ata_aux]
root        94  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [ata_sff/0]
root        95  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [ata_sff/1]
root        96  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [ata_sff/2]
root        97  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [ata_sff/3]
root        98  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [ata_sff/4]
root        99  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [ata_sff/5]
root       100  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [ata_sff/6]
root       101  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [ata_sff/7]
root       102  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [ksuspend_usbd]
root       103  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [khubd]
root       104  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kseriod]
root       105  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md/0]
root       106  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md/1]
root       107  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md/2]
root       108  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md/3]
root       109  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md/4]
root       110  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md/5]
root       111  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md/6]
root       112  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md/7]
root       113  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md_misc/0]
root       114  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md_misc/1]
root       115  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md_misc/2]
root       116  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md_misc/3]
root       117  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md_misc/4]
root       118  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md_misc/5]
root       119  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md_misc/6]
root       120  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [md_misc/7]
root       121  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [linkwatch]
root       123  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root       124  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:16 [kswapd0]
root       125  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Oct10   0:00 [ksmd]
root       126  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Oct10   0:28 [khugepaged]
root       127  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [aio/0]
root       128  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [aio/1]
root       129  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [aio/2]
root       130  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [aio/3]
root       131  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [aio/4]
root       132  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [aio/5]
root       133  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [aio/6]
root       134  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [aio/7]
root       135  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [crypto/0]
root       136  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [crypto/1]
root       137  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [crypto/2]
root       138  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [crypto/3]
root       139  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [crypto/4]
root       140  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [crypto/5]
root       141  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [crypto/6]
root       142  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [crypto/7]
root       149  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kthrotld/0]
root       150  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kthrotld/1]
root       151  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kthrotld/2]
root       152  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kthrotld/3]
root       153  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kthrotld/4]
root       154  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kthrotld/5]
root       155  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kthrotld/6]
root       156  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kthrotld/7]
root       158  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       159  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [usbhid_resume]
root       160  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [deferwq]
root       192  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kdmremove]
root       193  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kstriped]
root       306  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root       307  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       373  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [virtio-blk]
root       450  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   4:13 [kdmflush]
root       452  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       476  0.6  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10  28:44 [jbd2/dm-0-8]
root       477  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwr]
root       562  0.0  0.0  11388   340 ?        S<s  Oct10   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root       735  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [virtio-net]
root       747  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:12 [vballoon]
root       891  0.0  0.0  12396   548 ?        S<   Oct10   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root       898  0.0  0.0  12372   548 ?        S<   Oct10   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root       924  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [jbd2/vda1-8]
root       925  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwr]
root       928  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:21 [flush-253:0]
root      1028  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:02 [kauditd]
root      1069  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct10   5:45 [loop0]
root      1072  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   1:02 [kjournald]
root      1240  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:25 [flush-7:0]
root      1297  0.0  0.0  93156   752 ?        S<sl Oct10   0:04 auditd
root      1370  0.0  0.0 249084  1632 ?        Sl   Oct10   0:04 /sbin/rsyslogd
root      1385  0.0  0.0  18244   508 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:13 irqbalance --pi
named     1403  0.0  0.0 695468 20904 ?        Ssl  Oct10   0:01 /usr/sbin/named
494       1506  0.4  0.2 397536 68796 ?        Ssl  Oct10  17:44 memcached -d -p
root      1520  0.0  0.0  49184  2548 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:01 nginx: master p
root      1554  0.0  0.0  66224   580 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      1565  0.0  0.0 108300  1312 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bi
mysql     1837  266 56.8 20904568 13994308 ?   Sl   Oct10 11067:04 /usr/sbin/mys
root      1875  0.0  0.0  19600   980 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:00 /usr/sbin/dovec
dovenull  1883  0.0  0.0  42232  2388 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 dovecot/pop3-lo
dovenull  1884  0.0  0.0  42380  2632 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 dovecot/imap-lo
dovecot   1885  0.0  0.0  13304  1048 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 dovecot/anvil
root      1886  0.0  0.0  13436  1132 ?        S    Oct10   0:01 dovecot/log
dovenull  1889  0.0  0.0  42232  2388 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 dovecot/pop3-lo
dovenull  1891  0.0  0.0  42384  3112 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 dovecot/imap-lo
root      1895  0.0  0.0  16420  1780 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 dovecot/config
dovecot   1897  0.0  0.0  31536  1688 ?        S    Oct10   0:01 dovecot/auth
mailnull  1898  0.0  0.0  71116  5468 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:00 /usr/sbin/exim
root      1959  0.0  0.0 163752  4444 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:30 /usr/local/cpan
root      2068  0.0  0.0 163752  2172 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 spamd child
root      2094  0.0  0.0  66724  4136 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:31 /usr/local/apac
root      2117  0.0  0.0 138640  1376 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:00 pure-ftpd (SERV
root      2119  0.0  0.0 136136  1372 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 /usr/sbin/pure-
root      2134  0.0  0.0 116864   852 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:16 crond
root      2171  0.0  0.0 144528  4048 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:14 /usr/local/cpan
nobody    2539  0.2  0.0  57084 10576 ?        S    18:00   0:13 nginx: worker p
nobody    2540  0.3  0.0  57340 10860 ?        S    18:00   0:16 nginx: worker p
nobody    2541  0.2  0.0  57084 10572 ?        S    18:00   0:12 nginx: worker p
nobody    2542  0.3  0.0  57076 10720 ?        S    18:00   0:15 nginx: worker p
nobody    2543  0.3  0.0  56820 10484 ?        S    18:00   0:16 nginx: worker p
nobody    2544  0.3  0.0  57604 10848 ?        S    18:00   0:16 nginx: worker p
nobody    2545  0.3  0.0  57084 10576 ?        S    18:00   0:19 nginx: worker p
nobody    2546  0.3  0.0  57332 10816 ?        S    18:00   0:15 nginx: worker p
nobody    2547  0.3  0.0  59388 12732 ?        S    18:00   0:19 nginx: worker p
nobody    2548  0.3  0.0  57084 10576 ?        S    18:00   0:17 nginx: worker p
nobody    2549  0.3  0.0  57340 10960 ?        S    18:00   0:15 nginx: worker p
nobody    2550  0.2  0.0  57404 11172 ?        S    18:00   0:14 nginx: worker p
nobody    2551  0.3  0.0  57340 10864 ?        S    18:00   0:15 nginx: worker p
nobody    2552  0.2  0.0  57084 10576 ?        S    18:00   0:13 nginx: worker p
nobody    2553  0.3  0.0  57084 10580 ?        S    18:00   0:18 nginx: worker p
nobody    2554  0.2  0.0  57340 10668 ?        S    18:00   0:13 nginx: worker p
nobody    2555  0.0  0.0  49184  2164 ?        S    18:00   0:00 nginx: cache ma
root      2556  0.0  0.0  79392 10360 ?        S    18:00   0:00 /usr/local/cpan
root      2578  0.0  0.0  21104   328 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd
root      2687  0.0  0.0  71028  2976 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 cPhulkd - proce
root      2727  0.0  0.0  98480  7664 ?        S    Oct10   0:07 cpsrvd (SSL) -
root      2793  0.0  0.0 112824   796 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 cpdavd - accept
root      2907  0.0  0.0  37868  3128 ?        S    Oct10   0:08 queueprocd - wa
root      3286  0.0  0.0  37740  2016 ?        S    Oct10   0:01 tailwatchd
root      3304  0.0  0.0  26652  1276 ?        SN   Oct10   0:01 cpanellogd - sl
root      3453  0.0  0.0   4064   520 tty1     Ss+  Oct10   0:00 /sbin/mingetty
root      3461  0.0  0.0   4064   520 tty2     Ss+  Oct10   0:00 /sbin/mingetty
root      3470  0.0  0.0   4064   520 tty3     Ss+  Oct10   0:00 /sbin/mingetty
root      3485  0.0  0.0   4064   520 tty4     Ss+  Oct10   0:00 /sbin/mingetty
root      3490  0.0  0.0   4064   520 tty5     Ss+  Oct10   0:00 /sbin/mingetty
root      3496  0.0  0.0   4064   520 tty6     Ss+  Oct10   0:00 /sbin/mingetty
root      9933  0.0  0.0 160228 19892 ?        Ss   00:00   0:31 lfd - sleeping
nobody   13735  0.5  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    19:20   0:01 [htt] <defunct>
nobody   17640  0.5  0.0  68212  4780 ?        S    19:21   0:00 /usr/local/apac
nobody   17930  0.5  0.0  67804  4332 ?        S    19:21   0:00 /usr/local/apac
nobody   18246  0.5  0.0  67668  4196 ?        S    19:21   0:00 /usr/local/apac
nobody   18454  0.5  0.0  67532  4132 ?        S    19:21   0:00 /usr/local/apac
nobody   19903  0.5  0.0  67124  3708 ?        S    19:22   0:00 /usr/local/apac
nobody   23207  0.5  0.0  67260  3736 ?        S    19:23   0:00 /usr/local/apac
nobody   23505  0.5  0.0  67124  3672 ?        S    19:23   0:00 /usr/local/apac
nobody   23726  0.5  0.0  68212  4716 ?        S    19:23   0:00 /usr/local/apac
nobody   24165  0.5  0.0  67124  3652 ?        S    19:23   0:00 /usr/local/apac
root     24624  0.0  0.0 102024  4296 ?        Ss   18:42   0:00 sshd: root@pts/
nobody   24808  0.4  0.0  67124  3668 ?        S    19:23   0:00 /usr/local/apac
root     24809  0.0  0.0 108432  1976 pts/0    Ss+  18:42   0:00 -bash
username    26058  3.0  0.0 220424 19504 ?        S    19:24   0:00 /usr/bin/php /h
username    26068  3.0  0.0 220168 19484 ?        S    19:24   0:00 /usr/bin/php /h
root     26072  4.0  0.0 110236  1180 pts/1    R+   19:24   0:00 ps -aux
root     30516  0.0  0.0 102024  4300 ?        Ss   18:55   0:00 sshd: root@pts/
root     30597  0.0  0.0 100680  3736 ?        Ss   01:01   0:00 sshd: unknown [
sshd     30598  0.0  0.0  67568  1752 ?        S    01:01   0:00 sshd: unknown [
root     31251  0.0  0.0 108432  1980 pts/1    Ss   18:55   0:00 -bash
```

I recently installed memcached to resolve the high cpu usage because it kept calling db for every query. Now seems I have a memory issue.

I have a total of 24gb ram and still is not enough. I only allocated 64mb to memcache but it goes way over the limit. Any check or fixes I can do?

Comment: please format this nicely, for starters. Use edit and mark console output as code. And the output of `ps` might back your theory that memcached is using too much memory.

Comment: How do you know memcache is using too much memory? Your host still has 8GB of memory available to use so what is the issue?

Comment: where do you see free 8gb? I have total 24gb and using it all.

Comment: updated with output for ps -aux

Comment: You want to look at the line that reads "-/+ buffers/cache." It shows over 8GB free. It also might be a good idea to read up on how linux utilizes RAM

Comment: if I do have 8gb free why would it use swap instead of using what I already have?